# C#. Как из WinForm приложения запустить и выполнить код написанный для ConsoleApp?

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль

Есть проект на C# WinForm. Есть код для Консоли на С#. По нажатию кнопки в форме должен выполняться код для консоли и выводиться консоль. Как это реализовать?

Можно, как я понимаю, В том же solution создать проект под ConsoleApp и компилировать их вместе а потом просто запускать exe консоли как программу, но наверное есть и другие способы?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вам нужно запустить консольное приложение и перенаправить его вывод?

Comment: Не совсем наверное. Вот код(к примеру);

Comment: Ээээ... А именно `Console.WriteLine` — это обязательно? Можно вместо этого что-нибудь типа `editBox.Text += i.ToString() + "\n"`? А вместо `Thread.Sleep` — `await Task.Delay`?

Comment: Мне кажется @Ximik хочет, чтобы при запуске его приложения WinForms показывалось окно консоли, куда можно было бы делать вывод через `Console.WriteLine`. Если так, то достаточно в настройках проекта WinForms указать `Project Properties -> Application -> Output Type -> Console Application`.

Comment: @Romario: Ну, не совсем достаточно. `Thread.Sleep` будет приводить к зависаниям UI.

Comment: @Romario Если сделать так как вы советуете, то формы, вообще говоря, нормально работать перестанут. Попробуйте из консольного приложения запустить форму простым `Form.Show()`, много интересного увидите =) а в режиме диалога `Form.ShowDialog()` будет все ок.

Comment: @rdorn А вы точно поняли, что я сказал сделать? =) В проекте WinForms из шаблона предполагается наличие `Application.Run(new Form1())`, поэтому приложение не завершится пока форма не будет закрыта или явно не будет вызвана функция выхода из приложения.

Comment: @Romario полагаю что понял. На первый взгляд все действительно работает, но что-то меня в этом решении все же смущает, буду тестировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте консольное приложение, затем киньте в папку с проектом.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ConsoleApp.exe");
        this.Close();
    }
```